# Printing char multi dimensional arrays not working like I want to

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, printf, c-strings

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fisier;
    fisier = fopen("cnp.txt", "r");

    int cnpuri = 0;
    char cnp[10][13];

    while(1){
        fscanf(fisier, "%s", cnp[cnpuri]);
        cnpuri++;

        if(feof(fisier))
            break;
    }

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < cnpuri; i++){
        printf("%s \n", cnp[i]);
    }

    fclose(fisier);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the text I'm reading:

```
1234567890123
1763578126765
4156156546489
5749684631654
5498654168763
```

And this is what it shows in terminal:

```
12345678901231763578126765415615654648957496846316545498654168763
1763578126765415615654648957496846316545498654168763
415615654648957496846316545498654168763
57496846316545498654168763
5498654168763
```

Comment: Strings in C need to be NUL terminated. So a 13 digit string requires a 14 char array to store. Increase the second dimension of the array by at least 1.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the second size of the array

```
char cnp[10][13];
```

is not large enough to store the terminating zero character of entered strings.

Declare it at least like

```
char cnp[10][14];
```

Also change the while loop the following way

```
while( cnpuri < 10 && fscanf(fisier, "%s", cnp[cnpuri]) == 1)
{
    cnpuri++;
}
```

Comment: thanks, i was dumb to forget about the \0 character